# MapAnnotation producing publishing changes from within view updates Runtime Warnings

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, mapkit

I've attempted to use a simple `@FetchRequest` to return all the airports based on the `Airport` entity in CoreData and then feed this data to the `annotationItems` parameter within `Map`. The end goal is to render custom markers based on the data fetched.

When running the app, several Runtime Warnings are printed in the debug log (the runtime warnings trigger at `@main`), and even more, are printed when the map is moved around. The warning states: `[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.`

I've changed the `MapAnnotation` view to a simple `MapMarker` and the code runs fine without any warnings.

I am running this on Xcode Version 14.1 beta 3 (14B5033e) using Simulator Version 14.1 (986.3), running iOS 16.1. I have also tried Xcode Version 14.0.1 (14A400) using Simulator Version 14.0.1 (986.3), running iOS 16.0. Both of these produce the same results and warnings.

The full code used is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreData

struct AirportsView: View {
  // Fetch list of stored Airports from CoreData
  @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
  var airports: FetchedResults<Airport>
   
  @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
   
  var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
                annotationItems: airports,
                annotationContent: { airport in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: airport.latitude, longitude: airport.longitude)) {

                            LocationMapAnnotationView()
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                        }
                })
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

Any help regarding how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which line of code triggers the warning?

Comment: @Magnas Xcode is reporting it as `@main` which is no help but I believe it is to do with `MapAnnotation` that could be causing the errors since if I remove it in replacement for `MapMarker` it works but I have no clue why. I've also just checked and found that this error is still occurring even without any of the CoreData `@FetchRequest` code but just static mock data, giving the impression it's not to do with CoreData.

Comment: In `LocationMapAnnotationView` are you doing anything that changes `State` ? I’ve had these same warnings recently (for code that ran perfectly fine previously) and they can be a pain to track down.

Comment: No, it is just a simple view that shows a marker, a VStack, and some Image views. I've also just tried to run the Apple Annotation [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapannotation) in a new project and am also getting tons of Runtime Errors from that, so to me this seems like a much deeper issue than I thought. Seems like SwiftUI 4 packed more breaking changes than I first thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be that this fixes it (I don't really understand why, so if someone can explain why it works and why the previous way of doing it now doesn't that would be really appreciated)

I don't take credit for this, as it was a solution by another user called  `tonyayoub` on the [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711899?answerId=732977022#732977022)

This is what he found, the code that was producing the warning was:

```
struct AreaMap: View {

  @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion

  var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
  }
}
```

Where region was passed in the initializer of AreaMap from its parent view.
This resolved the issue:

```
struct AreaMap: View {

  @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion

  var body: some View {
    let binding = Binding(
      get: { self.region },
      set: { newValue in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.region = newValue
        }
      }
    )
    return Map(coordinateRegion: binding)
  }
}
```